# How do I create multiple instances of this different CLICK TO COPY on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy-paste

I have this CLICK TO COPY code that would help you copy a text to clipboard. How do I create multiple instances of this different CLICK TO COPY on same page.

Here is the code I have already.

```html
<p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure you properly copy text:</p>
<input type="text" value="12sDKsfHXYFKKshjBQZEVmQo4EBmDBvzY7" id="myInput" readonly><br><br>

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy Address
  </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  //tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;//
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: ";
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
```

I try to add in more instances of the code to be able to create more CLICK TO COPY buttons on the same page by changing the text value But it keeps selecting only the first text.

Comment: Just to be clear, Do you want to copy from multiple sources with a single button that you have? or it's like  multiple copy button to select from multiple sources?

Comment: I see ID attributes being used - an ID *must* be unique

Comment: The structure of the HTML fragment shown here - can that be tweaked slightly or is that firmly set?

Comment: How do you want the buttons to be placed? It would seem to make sense to have them placed next to the particular text to be copied - and that would help you associate each click with the right text - but it's not clear from your current layout.

Comment: Yes. Professor Abtonsius. The Html Fragment can be changed if it can solve the problem. I want different instances of “click to copy” that can copy different texts on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the ID attributes and assign a common parent to the elements shown here you can use other DOM navigation techniques to identify pieces of code quite easily.

The HTML from the original is wrapped in a `span` - the span will not affect presentation but allows use to access the `parentNode` property of an element and from there other selections can be made.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip button').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  /* within this function `this` refers to the button */
  let input=this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input');
      input.select();
      input.setSelectionRange(0, input.value.length);
      
  document.execCommand('copy');
  this.parentNode.innerHTML="Copied: " + input.value;
}))
```

```css
div.copy{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='copy'>
    <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure you properly copy text:</p>
    <input type="text" value="12sDKsfHXYFKKshjBQZEVmQo4EBmDBvzY7" readonly />

    <div class="tooltip">
        <button>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='copy'>
    <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure you properly copy text:</p>
    <input type="text" value="12sDKsfsdfsdfHXghjghjVmQo4EBmDBvzY7" readonly />

    <div class="tooltip">
        <button>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='copy'>
    <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Ensure you properly copy text:</p>
    <input type="text" value="1xxxswerHXYFKKshj56fgh8Qo4EBmDBvzY7" readonly />

    <div class="tooltip">
        <button>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea to group the elements, but the W3C validator is objecting to having divs elc within a span element.

Comment: Fair enough - the parent could be another `div` then with an inline display style if layout is not to be affected and w3c validity is important